# multi filtering using querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<ProductList.aspx>
<asp:DataList ID="dl_vendor" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <li>
               <a href = "ProductList.aspx?Vendor=<%# Eval("Vendor_Name")%>"><%# Eval("Vendor_Name")%></a>
           </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<asp:DataList ID="dl_category" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <a href = "ProductList.aspx?ProdCategory=<%# Eval("Product_Category")%>"><%# Eval("Product_Category")%></a>      
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>


<ProductList.aspx.cs>
protected void dl_Category_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string selectedProduct = dl_Category.SelectedItem.DataItem.ToString();
        string strQuery = "where Product_Category = '" + selectedProduct + "' ";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Products " + strQuery + " ", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        try
        {
        if (Request.QueryString["ProdCategory"] == dt.Rows[0][5].ToString())
        {
              Response.Redirect("ProductDetails.aspx?ProdID=" + selectedProduct);
        }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('No Product Found');</script>");
        }

         lv_Product.DataSourceID = null;
         lv_Product.DataSource = dt;
         lv_Product.DataBind();
```

How do I filter more than one parameter using querystring so that i get an output of ProductList.aspx?ProdCategory=......&Vendor=......

Currently I am only able to filter it one parameter at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a "All" entry to the top of each of your dropdown lists.  Then set that to be the default selected item.  Your code would then need to change from this:

```
string selectedProduct = dl_Category.SelectedItem.DataItem.ToString();
string strQuery = "where Product_Category = '" + selectedProduct + "' ";
```

to this:

```
string selectedCategory = dl_Category.SelectedItem.DataItem.ToString();
string selectedVendor = dl_Vendor.SelectedItem.DataItem.ToString();
string strQuery = "where Product_Category = '" + selectedCategory + "'" +
    " and Product_Vendor = '" + selectedVendor + "'";
```